# Parallel hyperparameter optimization techniques?

Tags: optimization, hyperparameter, bayesian, parallel

Most hyperparameter optimization technique want to evaluate points one by one.
I have an expensive optimization problem, but i can run hundreds of evaluations in parallel.
The dimension of the problem is around 20-30.
My variables are mostly continuous.

Is there any technique with open source, documented implementation available for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Bayesian optimisation is sequential in the sense that you need to know the value of the function for n point to decide through an acquisition criteria the next point to evaluate.

Maybe you could customize it to your problem so that the acquisition returns not one point but a batch of them, which you distribute at the next step.

You can also use an hybrid method. First run a classic grid search, distributed, and evaluate the function at many many points. Feed all this knowledge (points and objective value at these points) to a classic bayesian optimiser which will pick points one by one and finer tune the optimisation here. Not as optimal as the former, but less implementation work here.

Comment: The question is how to sample multiple point from the acquisition function? Is there software which does this out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

The python [hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/Parallelizing-Evaluations-During-Search-via-MongoDB) library will evaluate multiple trials in parallel, it's open source and there's a [paper](https://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2013/pdfs/bergstra_hyperopt.pdf).

Also I'm fairly sure AWS Sagemaker has a distributed Baysian algorithm, it doens't meet your criteria of open source though.